# Why is log4net throwing LockRecursionException?

Tags: c#, logging, exception, log4net

I upgraded log4net to version 1.2.13 from 1.2.11 and now it throws the following exception whenever my application throws an exception:

```
Error: log4net:ERROR Exception while logging
log4net:ERROR Exception while logging
Error: System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
    at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout)
    at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(TimeoutTracker timeout)
    at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
    at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterReadLock()
    at log4net.Util.ReaderWriterLock.AcquireReaderLock()
    at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
    at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
```

Logging works as usual when my application doesn't throw an exception. If someone can provide insight on why this might be happening I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful here.

Comment: Please share some code snippet which throws error. Refer msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lockrecursionexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  -- for reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In my application this apparently happens when a logger is accessed while logging a message. For example,

```
private static readonly ILog iLog = LogManager.GetLogger(
    MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

public void Configure(){
    iLog.InfoFormat("Found project '{0}'.", GetProject());
    ... do stuff ...
}


private string GetProject()
{
   string result = null;
   iLog.Debug("Trying to determine project.");
   .... do stuff ...
   return result;
}
```

Apart from avoiding this situation I haven't found a fix yet.

Edit: After switching to NLog, logging worked out of the box, so I guess it is a bug in log4net. By the way, switching was effortless and NLog is easier to use, too.

Answer (score 0):

log4net version 1.2.14 seems to have fixed this bug. See https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html

[Update] I could reproduce this issue even with 1.2.15. It so happened that my local log DB was filled up and hence was seeing this error multiple times.